# RSS Announcer/Application

Tags: windows-7, rss, notifications

I'm looking for a RSS (feed) reader that runs in the background and tells me in a pretty, non-intrusive way, a good popup perhaps, each time something new comes out in those feeds.

Notes:

- Windows 7
- Compatibility with common feeds

Comment: If you're currently using Windows 10, please refer to my answer at: http://superuser.com/a/978664/323140

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [RSS Bandit](http://rssbandit.org/) (freeware).  I find it the best way to read RSS feeds.  It can sync with the Windows Common Feeds list and Google Reader.  When it is minimised to the system tray, it gives notifications of new feeds.

I think there is a new version on the way which will have MS Office style ribbon toolbars, which hopefully can be hidden like on Office, to maximise screen space.

[image: RSS Bandit]

Comment: @Queops: Yeah, I am not too keen on the way it looks, but it works very well.

Comment: I got used to it already; has definitely too many stuff not needed and couple stuff that could be tweaked/added but will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Feed Notifier](http://www.feednotifier.com/) is built specifically for this purpose.

> Feed Notifier is a Windows application
>   that resides in the system tray and
>   displays pop-up notifications on your
>   desktop when new items arrive in your
>   subscribed RSS or Atom feeds. By
>   default, the pop-ups look like this…

[image]

*Disclaimer: I am the developer of this app*